# Monitoring phone usage and limits

Tags: data-monitoring, data-plan

I have 100 minutes of free talk every week, 25 free SMS every week and 2GB of Internet data usage in a month. Nothing alerts me when one of these thresholds has been exceeded.

Is there any way to keep track of my outgoing calls and messages, and then receive an alert when I'm going to exceed my limit? It would be preferable if the threshold would reset automatically every week and be configurable.

Comment: Please don't ask for "an app that does X". Not only does that skirt on being a shopping recommendation (which are off-topic) but you've also already chosen a solution. Instead, ask about the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Some networks allow you to check how much you have used such as O2.  If you have ICS or Jelly Bean there is a Data Usage listing in settings.

Alternatively try apps like these
http://www.theandroidsoul.com/best-android-data-usage-apps-for-monitoring-3g2gwi-fi-usage/

Comment: My network have provided an app to check this, but is really slow, and usually crash. :(

Answer (score 3):

[DroidStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nitro.phonestats) does this for calls, SMS, and data:

[image: DroidStats widgets] [image: DroidStats Notification]

You can place widgets on your homescreen<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HIvf.jpg)</sup> or, with the pro version, even inside your notification area<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaviA.jpg)</sup>. Limits can of course be configured. It even shows data usage on a per-app basis. Statistics can show your most-called (and most-called-from) contacts, and more.

As for data, [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog) even can go a step further and, provided you have [Apndroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro) installed, disable 3g data when a configured threshold is reached.